# Copy column to another column only if field is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL question which may be basic to some but is confusing me. Here is an example of a table:

```
buu_properties_products (price, years, area, covered_area)
```

Now I want to copy the `area` column fields into the `covered_area` fields but only if the `covered_area` field is empty.

I have almost 1000 products in this table and I need to update those column without deleting the covered_area values when they are present.

I am running MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 11):

Depends what 'empty' means. If it means `NULL`:

```
UPDATE buu_properties_products
SET covered_area = area
WHERE covered_area IS NULL
```

If it means an empty string:

```
UPDATE buu_properties_products
SET covered_area = area
WHERE covered_area = ''
```

If it means either:

```
UPDATE buu_properties_products
SET covered_area = area
WHERE covered_area IS NULL OR covered_area = ''
```